# Is there a faster clothoid equation?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I've been reading-up on various [clothoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) formulas and I am looking for a very specific equation to find the $(X Y)$ coordinates of any point on the clothoid that does not involve looping though this formula:
$$\binom{X=\int_{0}^{L} \cos t^2 \Delta t}{Y=\int_{0}^{L} \sin t^2 \Delta t}$$
$L$ is the length of the clothoid when one end is straight, $t$ is the current distance along the clothoid, and $\Delta t$ is the distance moved at each step.  $X$ and $Y$ are then multiplied by the scale of the spiral.  The smaller the value of $\Delta t$, the more accurate the result is, but at the expense of processing power.

Is there an equation available that can take a specific distance along the clothoid and give an exact $(X Y)$ value?

Comment: You can use [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). In a computer program, using floating-point numbers, the Fresnel integral can be evaluated relatively quickly as a power series expansion, because the magnitude of the terms is decreasing; you can simply calculate enough terms until the terms become too small to affect the result.

Comment: So, does $n$ simply get incremented with each iteration?  If I remember correctly, the answer is yes, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, you increment $n$ by one each iteration, when calculating terms in the power series expansion. However, note that if $C_{n-1}$ is the term for $n-1$ in the Fresnel C integral, then $$C_{n} = -C_{n-1} \frac{x^4 (4 n - 3) }{(2 n)(4 n + 1)}$$ and similarly for the Fresnel S integral,$$S_{n} = -S_{n-1} \frac{x^4 (4 n - 1)}{(2 n + 1)(4 n + 3)}$$so you can basically precalculate the constant factors (of $n$), and get the next term by multiplying the previous term by that constant factor depending only on $n$, and by $x^4$ (here, $x = L$). That is what makes the power series expansion fast.

Comment: If this was a programming question, I could provide pseudocode...

Comment: That answers my questions.  Thanks.  At Wolfram, the equations seem to only take about 10 iterations depending on the value of $x$.

Comment: Your equation for C(x) will result in a divide by zero error.

Comment: No, it does not. You've just implemented it wrong. You probably didn't realize that the above formula for the $n$'th term is only valid for $n \ge 1$, and that $C_0 = x$, as shown in the [Fresnel integral Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) I linked to earlier.

Comment: Sorry about the very late reply.  I just now got around to implementing the formula on the wiki page linked.  [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxOf2r1MAQIHVAw9dizUbfYyIqM945PB/view) are the results.  Blue line is the expected result using the sin/sos functions for C(x) and S(x).  Red line is the actual result using the fresnel integral.  After just over 1.75 turns, the math stops working on the fresnel integrals.  Limit is 25 steps per vertex.  Lower step count reduces the time until breakdown.  Also, I couldn't get your equations to work.

Comment: 25 steps limit is artificial. just go on until the term becomes small enough. 4-5 turns is doable. for more, the Taylor series method with double floating point precision becomes inadequate, as the interim terms grow larger than $10^{16}$ in magnitude and there's a loss of numerical precision in the overall sum of terms.

Comment: I did notice that.  The image was generated with single precision.  I switched to double precision and got slightly over 4.5 turns with a limit of 64 steps per vertex.